# Need to add parameters in Friendly URL in Liferay 7.1 for a basic page

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-7

Can anyone guide me how to configure a Friendly URL for a basic Liferay page(not for a portlet page)

This is what I want to acheive:

I have a Baisc Liferay page with a url:

```
http://localhost:8080/categories
```

I want to add two parameters as /diamond/rings(diamond and rings), which is a dynamic value.

Example: I want a url like:

```
http://loclahost:8080/categories/diamond/rings (like http://localhost:8080/categories/:category/:product)
```

Were, reading :category and :product I will get the value as diamond and rings.

I checked the Friendly URL feature in Liferay following [this link](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-1/making-urls-friendlier), but this explains how to configure friendly url for a portlet page, But I dont have any portlet I just have a basic Liferay page as Categories.

So I don't know where to place the routes.xml file inside Liferay. It will be greatly helpful if any one guide me how to configure friendly URL without having a portlet. i.e how to configure a friendly URL for a basic Liferay page.

Comment: This is dangerously close to asking for documentation / a tutorial - i.e. [offtopic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for SO. Also, as friendly URLs typically contain a `/-/` after the page (e.g. I'd rather expect them to look like `/categories/-/diamond/ring`, I guess that you can't go with pure configuration in route.xml and will have to find a different place for a custom implementation of resolving to the requested page. And, indeed, implementing friendly URLs is typically done for your own portlets. Lastly, you tag `liferay-6` and `liferay-7` - which *exactly* is it that you want?

Comment: @olafkock thanks for replying. I want the url to be like this, /categories/diamond/ring and not as this  /categories/-/diamond/ring. Can you please tell me where should I do the changes for that. I am using Liferay 7.1, so if you guide for this it will be greatly helpful.

Comment: @OlafKock Can you help me on the above.

Comment: At the moment: No. You'll have to find out where the URLs are mapped to pages and tweak that mechanism. Don't look for friendlyURLs, as they're there to omit parameters from a particular portlet, and will contain `/-/`. Parse the URL left to right, find out what part of the URL denotes a page, and do whatever you need with the rest. Beware of ambiguities.